# Div is not rotating around its centre using jquery keyframes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two wheels divs. The wheels should rotate around their centre of origin but instead, they are doing a circular motion as shown below:

[image: wheelDuringMotion]

This is the CSS code for the wheel:

```
    .wheel1 img{
        width: 210px;
        position: relative;
        top:-320px;
        left:42px;
        /*animation: wheelRotation linear .99s infinite;*/
    }
    .wheel2 img{
        width: 225px;
        position: relative;
        top: -540px;
        left: 255px;            
        /*animation: wheelRotation linear .99s infinite;*/
    }
```

I am using jQuery keyframes to enable CSS animation from javascript. For the wheels, I am using `wheelRotation` keyframe with `360deg` rotation angle.

Below is how I add the animation sequence in JS:

```
   $.keyframe.define([{
            name: 'carMove',
            '100%': {
                'transform': 'translateX(-500vw)'
            }
          }, {
            name: 'wheelRotation',
            '100%': {
                'transform': 'rotate(360deg)'
            }
            }, {
              name: 'shake',
              '0%': {
                'transform': 'translateY(-5px)'
              },
              '50%': {
                'transform': 'translateY(5px)'
              },
              '100%': {
                'transform': 'translateY(-5px)'
            }  
        }]);
    });
```

and this is how the animation is played:

```
    function play(animation) {
      
        $('.track').resetKeyframe(function() {
            switch (animation) {
                case 'normal':
                $('.wheel1').playKeyframe({
                    name: 'wheelRotation',
                    duration: "5000ms",
                    timingFunction: 'linear',
                    iterationCount: 'infinite'
                  });

                $('.wheel2').playKeyframe({
                  name: 'wheelRotation',
                  duration: "5000ms",
                  iterationCount: 'infinite',
                  timingFunction: 'linear'
                });

                $('.track').playKeyframe({
                    name: 'carMove',
                    duration: "13s",
                    timingFunction: 'linear',
                    iterationCount: 'infinite',
                    direction: 'normal',
                    fillMode: 'forwards'
                  });

                  $('.car').playKeyframe({
                    name: 'shake',
                    duration: "3s",
                    timingFunction: 'linear',
                    iterationCount: 'infinite',
                    direction: 'normal',
                    fillMode: 'forwards'
                  });
                break;
            }
            
        })
    }
```

the wheel and track animation are fine, but the wheel are not rotating around their centre of origin. Why is this happening? I am not sure where the problem is coming from. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Below is the solution:

I had to make sure that the div position is set when the animation starts as shown in the code below and removes the `position: relative;` from the CSS code. By including `$('.wheel1').css({....})` and `$('.wheel2').css({....})`, I was able to remove all the CSS code for .wheel1 and .wheel2 as they are not necessary anymore.

```
function play(animation)  {
      $('.wheel1').css({'width': '210px','top': '-303px','left': '420px','position': 'relative','transform-origin': 'center'});
      $('.wheel2').css({'width': '210px','top': '-485px','left': '195px','position': 'relative','transform-origin': 'center'});
}
```